# Get coordinates from Google places API in Symfony Ivory Bundle

Tags: google-places

I'm on a Symfony Project where I have to assign an address to a user. Then I have to show their position on a map.
I use Ivory Google Maps Bundle. Markers work with coordonates.
So the I think the best way to do it is to use Google Places and get
the coordonates.
And then assign it to the markers.

The problem is: How to get coordinates from Google Places API and store them with doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundle can query [The Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) which gives you informations about a place with cordinates.

```
// Requests the ivory google map geocoder service
$geocoder = $this->get('ivory_google_map.geocoder');

// Geocode an address
$response = $geocoder->geocode('YOUR_ADDRESS_HERE');

// Get the result corresponding to your address
foreach($response->getResults() as $result) {
    var_dump($result->getGeometry()->getLocation());
}
```

Here's the [full doc](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage/services/geocoding/ivory_geocoder.md) !

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed !

Comment: Glad to help ! Please accept my answer if you're happy with. ;)